# Martingale and Stochastic equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Using the Ito formula, I can show that the martingale $$
 Z_{t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}\exp -\frac{B_t^2}{2(1-t)}\qquad 0\leq t<1
$$ admits the following differential $$ dZ_t=-\frac{B_t}{1-t}Z_tdB_t. $$
 Is it the form of a stochastic differential equation?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this has the form of a stochastic differential equation. If you want the correctness of your equation checked, please add your strategy and tricks for the computation.

Comment: My equation is the form $dZ_t=\sigma(t,\omega)Z_tdB_t$ and the resolution is the same that the SDE with linear coefficients.

Comment: Yes, I meant that to me it seems that taking the derivative of the first equation (to see that the drift term cancels etc.) is a vast computation. Are there any tricks to make it short and lucid?